# sed Pattern matching between two strings only display first match

Tags: awk, sed

I am trying to use the sed pattern match between two strings to parse a file and find the first match , using this first match , I am trying to perform some actions in a loop iteratively , the sed pattern match between two strings prints all matches , I am only looking to get the first match :

File :

```
  },{
   "prefix" : "AD",
   "prefix" : "CQ",
   "last" : 0,
   "last" : 0,
   "month" : 0,
   "month" : 5,
   "today": 0,
   "today": 0,
   "yesterday": 2,
   "yesterday": 0,
   "agents": 0
  },{
   "prefix" : "CS",
   "prefix" : "AE",
   "last" : 1,
   "last" : 0,
   "month" : 130,
   "month" : 0,
   "today": 0,
   "today": 20,
   "yesterday": 0,
   "yesterday": 38,
   "agents": 0
  },{
   "prefix" : "AF",
   "prefix" : "CZ",
   "last" : 0,
   "last" : 0,
   "month" : 6,
```

I am trying to extract between prefix and agents , but only the first match using the below sed command:

```
sed -n '/prefix/,/agents/p' /var/saas/stats/usage_1499245200.json.2 >> /var/saas/stats/try
```

Is there a way I can only extract first match from the file during first iteration `usage_1499245200.json.2` and execute the loop .

Thanks,
Sriram.V

Comment: what should be the final result(including loop) ?

Comment: why the python tag again? this has nothing to do with python. This aint even valid JSON, well the keys are duplicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could add a command to quit when `agents` is encountered:

```
sed -n -e '/prefix/,/agents/p' -e '/agents/q'
```

result:

```
   "prefix" : "AD",
   "prefix" : "CQ",
   "last" : 0,
   "last" : 0,
   "month" : 0,
   "month" : 5,
   "today": 0,
   "today": 0,
   "yesterday": 2,
   "yesterday": 0,
   "agents": 0
```

Comment: Thank you very much , also every time , I read this file , I am performing a set of actions under a loop , post performing these actions , I am deleting lines again based on same pattern match , when I try to use :                             sed -n -e '/prefix/,/agents/d' -e '/agents/q' /var/saas/stats/usage_1499245200.json.2  , this suppresses output because of -n , how can I delete inplace without deleting successive matches and only deleting first one , should I use -i ?

Comment: `-i` only overwrites the current file. but that looks like a completely new question. I suggest that you ask another question (it's not an issue, you can even link it to that one)

Answer (score 2):

Using `awk` :

```
[akshay@localhost test]$ awk '/prefix/{found=1}found;/agents/{exit}' infile
   "prefix" : "AD",
   "prefix" : "CQ",
   "last" : 0,
   "last" : 0,
   "month" : 0,
   "month" : 5,
   "today": 0,
   "today": 0,
   "yesterday": 2,
   "yesterday": 0,
   "agents": 0
```

***Input***

```
[akshay@localhost test]$ cat infile
},{
   "prefix" : "AD",
   "prefix" : "CQ",
   "last" : 0,
   "last" : 0,
   "month" : 0,
   "month" : 5,
   "today": 0,
   "today": 0,
   "yesterday": 2,
   "yesterday": 0,
   "agents": 0
  },{
   "prefix" : "CS",
   "prefix" : "AE",
   "last" : 1,
   "last" : 0,
   "month" : 130,
   "month" : 0,
   "today": 0,
   "today": 20,
   "yesterday": 0,
   "yesterday": 38,
   "agents": 0
  },{
   "prefix" : "AF",
   "prefix" : "CZ",
   "last" : 0,
   "last" : 0,
   "month" : 6,
```

Comment: thta's the equivalent awk version, awk is in the tags, so good answer.

Comment: Thank you very much , also every time , I read this file , I am performing a set of actions under a loop , post performing these actions , I am deleting lines again based on same pattern match , when I try to use : sed -n -e '/prefix/,/agents/d' -e '/agents/q' /var/saas/stats/usage_1499245200.json.2 , this suppresses output because of -n , how can I delete inplace without deleting successive matches and only deleting first one , should I use -i ?

Comment: @sriram2207, if you have `gawk` then you can use `gawk -i inplace -v INPLACE_SUFFIX=.bak`, otherwise `awk '{ }' infile >tmpfile && mv tmpfile infile`

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: Thank you :)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre notice that in the awk solution you only specify the terminating condition (`/agents/`) once while in the sed version you have to specify it twice? Duplicate code is bad code. There are other advantages to the awk approach too (e.g efficiency and adaptability) - this is the right solution, sed is **only** for `s/old/new/`.

Comment: @EdMorton I know you are partial to `awk` :) I was answering with `sed` because 1) OP started with `sed` 2) the question is tagged with `python` so caught my filter. So I removed the `python` tag (someone put it back, why?) and since I could answer, I did.

Comment: @EdMorton also sometimes the "best" answer (which is also the most upvoted) isn't the one OP accepts. The one OP accepts is the one which is the closest to his/her attempt (that's human). Cheers.

Comment: I'm actually not any more partial to awk than I am to sed or grep or any other tool. I probably use sed more than awk on a daily basis. There's just the right tool for the right job and if the job at hand is `s/old/new/` the the right tool is sed, and if the job is `g/re/p` then the right tool is grep, otherwise it's `awk` (or some other general purpose text manipulation tool if you don't mind installing it).